# Manipulating inner html with string methods then placing it in pages that have repetitive data

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to manipulate the content generated by a WordPress plugin so that it matches the styling for the rest of my site.  Each block of data (of which there are 30 blocks on a page) has a number of  tags with various class names .
Here is an example:

```
<div class="sa_widget_sermons_row">
    <div class="sermon">
        <div class="sa_widget_title">
            Title_text
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            Speaker_Name, Date&nbsp;|&nbsp;Series&nbsp;|&nbsp;Topic
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...repeat again for the next set of data...
```

If I use something like the following jQuery:

```
$('.sa_widget_sermons_row > .info').html($('.sa_widget_sermons_row > .info').html().replace(/\|/g, '<br/>'));
```

...it replaces the | but it puts the same data (the first set) in every div.info.

I tried using an each() function to no avail.  And using 'this' in the above target argument breaks it.

How do I get it to retrieve the inner html, manipulate it, and put it back in the same place?

Note: if it is helpful to know - the entire set of blocks is wrapped in div.sa_widget_content as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback

```
$('.sa_widget_sermons_row .info').html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/\|/g, '<br/>');
});
```

or a loop

```
$('.sa_widget_sermons_row .info').each(function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/\|/g, '<br/>') );
});
```

to target each element, not all of them at once.

Note that `.info` is not a direct child of `.sa_widget_sermons_row`, there's a `.sermon` element between them so remove the "direct child selector" (`>`)

Comment: That did it.  I had tried the latter solution you supplied, but I think I tried to use replaceWith() rather than what you did.
Is there any benefit to using one over the other?

Comment: I like the callback better, but in reality they are pretty much the same, and you won't notice any difference.

Comment: For me the loop is more readable...but I haven't used jQuery hardly at all.